# Want to interactively sort values in a SSRS matrix with column and row groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've searched around a bit and haven't found an answer, so I'm a little nervous this isn't possible.

I've been adding interactive sort to row groups and it has been working just fine, but I'm getting stuck when I try to add it to a column group. For example, I have a row group called Agency_Ref and a column group called Nutrition.

In the nutrition grouping, the expression is =Sum(Fields!Weight.Value) / Sum(Fields!Weight.Value , "Agency_Ref") so that it displays the percentage of the particular nutritional attribute for the agency row grouping. When I add that expression to the sort by expression in interactive sorting, I don't get an error but the sorting doesn't work. It pretends to sort and just stays in the same order.

Any thoughts?

Comment: First question, what version of SSRS? Second question (and this always seems to get me), have you tried adjusting your expression to an `IIF` statement to remove the possibility of a divide by 0 error?

Comment: I'm using 11.0.5058.0 . I have tried that (=IIF(Sum(Fields!Weight.Value , "Agency_Ref") = 0, "", Sum(Fields!Weight.Value) / Sum(Fields!Weight.Value , "Agency_Ref"))), and I have the same problem where the sorting just doesn't work.